# How to set Django channels self.scope["user"] with Javascript (React)

Tags: django, reactjs, django-channels

I am using the following technologies:

Django Channels 2.1.2, ReactJS + reconnecting-websocket package

For consumers.py

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        me = self.scope['user']
        print(str(self.scope['user']))
```

For routinig.py

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url(r"^chat/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$", ChatConsumer),
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

For ReactJS, I'm connecting with the socket with

```
import ReconnectingWebSocket from 'reconnecting-websocket'

...

const rws = new ReconnectingWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/30/')
```

But Django is not picking up any user in scope?

For React, I'm storing user and token in cookies.

I believe it's a ReactJS fault but can somebody please help me out? Thanks!